# Comparing lists of integers and then ordering them based on similarity. 

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of players that each contain a list of skill ratings.
What I am trying to do is order those players based on the ratings matched to a specific search list.

Here is an example of four players:

```
        List<Skill> skillsA = new List<Skill>();
        List<Skill> skillsB = new List<Skill>();
        List<Skill> skillsC = new List<Skill>();
        List<Skill> skillsD = new List<Skill>();

        skillsA.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Speed", Value = 1 });
        skillsA.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Agility", Value = 5 });
        skillsA.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Strength", Value = 3 });
        skillsA.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Endurance", Value = 4 });

        skillsB.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Speed", Value = 5 });
        skillsB.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Agility", Value = 2 });
        skillsB.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Strength", Value = 1 });
        skillsB.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Endurance", Value = 3 });

        skillsC.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Speed", Value = 5 });
        skillsC.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Agility", Value = 3 });
        skillsC.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Strength", Value = 2 });
        skillsC.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Endurance", Value = 2 });

        skillsD.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Speed", Value = 1 });
        skillsD.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Agility", Value = 2 });
        skillsD.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Strength", Value = 5 });
        skillsD.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Endurance", Value = 4 });

        Player A = new Player() { Skills = skillsA };
        Player B = new Player() { Skills = skillsB };
        Player C = new Player() { Skills = skillsC };
        Player D = new Player() { Skills = skillsD };
```

This would be the search list I compare to:

```
        List<Skill> matchSkill = new List<Skill>();

        matchSkill.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Speed", Value = 5 });
        matchSkill.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Agility", Value = 2 });
        matchSkill.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Strength", Value = 1 });
        matchSkill.Add(new Skill() { Name = "Endurance", Value = 1 });

        SkillSearch SkillSearch = new SkillSearch() { Skills = matchSkill };
```

I should get back a list of players ordered PlayerB, PlayerC, PlayerD, PlayerA

The skill lists will always be the same size and in the same order. The skills always range from 1-5. I have tried comparing the difference between the values using absolute value. For example if a search is for a (3) 2 and 4 would be a closer match than 1 or 5.

In short if you just look at them as numeric array's you would have:

```
        search = { 5, 2, 1, 1}

        playerb = { 5, 2, 1, 3} : difference {0,0,0,2} (2 total)
        playerc = { 5, 3, 2, 2} : difference {0,1,1,1} (3 total)
        playerd = { 1, 2, 5, 4} : difference {4,0,4,3} (11 total)
        playera = { 1, 5, 3, 4} : difference {4,3,2,3} (12 total)
```

How would I order these using C#? I would prefer a linq result. I am just not sure how to get these to order.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I forgot to add the question...

Comment: Seems like you have chosen Manhattan Distance as your distance measure. Well, what's the problem? You need to calculate the sum of absolute differences between two sets of skills and rank them by lowest distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming classes:

```
public class Skill
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; } 
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

You may replace the sequences of `List<T>.Add` calls with [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
Player[] players = new Player[]
{
    new Player
    { 
        Name = "A", 
        Skills = new Skill[]
        {
            new Skill { Name = "Speed", Value = 1 },
            new Skill { Name = "Agility", Value = 5 },
            new Skill { Name = "Strength", Value = 3 },
            new Skill { Name = "Endurance", Value = 4 },
        }
    },
    new Player
    { 
        Name = "B", 
        Skills = new Skill[]
        {
            new Skill { Name = "Speed", Value = 5 },
            new Skill { Name = "Agility", Value = 2 },
            new Skill { Name = "Strength", Value = 1 },
            new Skill { Name = "Endurance", Value = 3 },
        }
    },
    new Player
    { 
        Name = "C", 
        Skills = new Skill[]
        {
            new Skill { Name = "Speed", Value = 5 },
            new Skill { Name = "Agility", Value = 3 },
            new Skill { Name = "Strength", Value = 2 },
            new Skill { Name = "Endurance", Value = 2 },
        }
    },
    new Player
    { 
        Name = "D", 
        Skills = new Skill[]
        {
            new Skill { Name = "Speed", Value = 1 },
            new Skill { Name = "Agility", Value = 2 },
            new Skill { Name = "Strength", Value = 5 },
            new Skill { Name = "Endurance", Value = 4 },
        }
    }
};

Skill[] matchSkills = new Skill[]
{
    new Skill { Name = "Speed", Value = 5 },
    new Skill { Name = "Agility", Value = 2 },
    new Skill { Name = "Strength", Value = 1 },
    new Skill { Name = "Endurance", Value = 1 },
};
```

Next, you should construct a `Dictionary<string, Skill>` for the `matchSkills` collection; this would allow you to quickly look up skills by name:

```
var matchSkillsDictionary = matchSkills.ToDictionary(matchSkill => matchSkill.Name);
```

Finally, you can use the LINQ `OrderBy` operation to sort your players in descending order of sums of skill differences. We shall use two intermediate functions to help keep things legible:

```
Func<Skill, int> getSkillDiff = skill => Math.Abs(skill.Value - matchSkillsDictionary[skill.Name].Value);
Func<Player, int> getPlayerDiff = player => player.Skills.Sum(getSkillDiff);
IEnumerable<Player> orderedPlayers = players.OrderBy(getPlayerDiff);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I would have used collection initializers if my application required values hard coded added from a loop such as the example. The players and skills will initially be populated from an Entity Framework result. My initial code would have leveraged a proc, however it seemed easier to have a matching searchskills list to compare too. Thanks so much.

Comment: Makes sense re collection initializers; I should have assumed you wouldn’t be using hard-coded data :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
players.OrderBy(player => player.Skills.Zip(matchSkills, (pl, sr) => Math.Abs(pl.Value - sr.Value)).Sum())
```

players is the array { A, B, C, D }.

Fixed the missing ".Skills" and ".Value" parts thanks to Douglas.

Comment: Operator cannot be applied to "Math.Abs(pl - sr)"? Perhaps I am not assigning search correctly?

Comment: Can't check it until Sunday, so you can try to see for yourself. Here is the Zip doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx. I'll check my answer and will update my post.

Answer (score 2):

**Reply** to Dmitry Polyanitsa:

I think this is what you mean:

```
players.OrderBy(player => player.Skills.Zip(matchSkills, (pl, sr) => Math.Abs(pl.Value - sr.Value)).Sum());
```

However, you’re assuming that the skills of all players (and of the match set) are always in identical order. If one player defines `Speed, Agility, Strength, Endurance`, the other cannot define `Agility, Speed, Strength, Endurance`.

**Edit**: Actually, your assumption was correct. The question states: “The skill lists will always be the same size and in the same order.” My apologies about missing that.

In this case, your solution is probably more efficient than my original proposal, since it avoids the overhead of the name lookup.

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed that part in the question. And yeah, I agree with you on the skills order.

Comment: Anyway, it's always nice to have a straightforward solution and a more clear and scalable one.